# error while running android application

Tags: android

hello sir my emmulator gives an error while running aoppliaction.

```
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:670)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

[2010-12-27 14:40:24 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:573)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:670)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're surely going to have to provide some source code along with that error.  Obviously you have a null pointer somewhere.  Android is trying to access something but you forgot to put it there!

Please share some source code to fix your problem faster.

Comment: package hello.example.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class helloandroid extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: That is not going to be enough source code.  The stack trace tells us that your error starts on line 65 of sendHelloCommands and continues to like 142 in SendHELO. Please edit your original question with the source code.

Comment: still my emulator gives that type of error                             [2010-12-27 15:17:37 - helloandroid] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
[2010-12-27 15:17:37 - helloandroid] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2010-12-27 15:17:37 - helloandroid] Launch canceled!
[2010-12-27 15:17:38 - helloandroid] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=hello.example.com/.helloandroid }

Comment: Sorry but that error is nothing similar to the previous one.  The error blatantly says that you do not have enough storage space. The two errors don't seem to have any connection.

Comment: sir please tell me we have to create seprate avd for each project in android

Comment: Each Android project/Eclipse Project may use the same AVD.  If you run two projects or two instances of the same project simultaneously, you will need more than 1 AVD.

Comment: sir can you explain me the logic behind arrayadapter in android means what is the use and how it works

Comment: You mark this question as answered and search a bit on SOF for information on the ArrayAdapter.  If you can't find anything, post another question on SOF.